# MySQL server 5.5 , my.ini settings

Tags: mysql, mysql5.5

There are a view things that don't match in my MySQL .ini file.

For example, everything that I have read/learned is to use

> config_settings = value

however, in my configuration file there are:

> config-setting = value

like myisam-block-size instead of myisam_block_size.

Can this cause issues, should I edit them to the _ instead of -?

Another question I have, in my config file I have open_files_limit = 500, but whenever I do a show variables the open_files_limit is 7048. Why would this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The configuration file use the dash (`-`)
- The variable name use the underscore (`_`)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_open-files-limit

> Another question I have, in my config file I have open_files_limit =
>   500, but whenever I do a show variables the open_files_limit is 7048.
>   Why would this be?

It sounds like someone has changed the `open_files_limit` value without restarting MySQL.

Comment: I did a net stop mysql, net start mysql to see if that was indeed the problem - but it wasn't. The open files limit was actually lower than the 5000 I set it to.

Comment: What is its value?